# Parallel instances via terraform variables?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am confounded by what terraform variables are supposed to do. Right now they seem awfully useless to resolve my specific requirement, perhaps I'm really barking up the wrong tree. Let's say I have a config like this:

```
variable "majorVersion" {
  type        = "string"
}

module "media-assets" {
  majorVersion   = "${var.majorVersion}"
  region         = "us-east-1"
  bucket         = "uploads-${var.majorVersion}"
  source         = "./modules/media-assets"
  user           = "appics-production"
}
```

Let's assume simply the assets module defines S3 buckets for now. All goes well if I run terraform like so:

```
terraform apply -var="majorVersion=v1"
```

However, if I run it again with

```
terraform apply -var="majorVersion=v2"
```

I want terraform to leave the resources of v1 alone! Instead terraform wants to tear down v1!! How can I accomplish a parametrised set of configurations without having to write the whole shebang all over again for each version? It seems tedious and beside the point!

Comment: From a high level standpoint what you are doing here is upgrading your infrastructure from one version to the next iterative version. Most software is written to replace older versions with newer versions during an upgrade. What do you want to accomplish here from an architecture standpoint?

Comment: Hi Matt. Essentially we need to be able to run several versions of an API to provide a gracful transition period for clients to update. However, I would like to avoid fundamental discussions on the issue of versioning REST APIs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html)

Workspace is your friend. You use workspaces to switch between 'setups' without having to touch your scripts. These 'setups' can be versions, environments, whatnot.

To achieve your specific need, you could have this in your variable.tf

```
variable "majorVersion" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    v1 = "v1"
    v2 = "v2"
  }
}


module "media-assets" {
  majorVersion   = "${var.majorVersion[terraform.workspace]}"
}
```

Before you run your apply command, select the right workspace

```
terraform workspace select v1
```

Although, you can probably see that you will need to add to the majorVersion map as you go. For that, I would suggest leaving versioning out of terraform scripts.

Comment: This is a great tip, unfortunately I can't use it so simply because I already need to compartmentalise the project in workspaces based on another criteria. Perhaps that can be rewritten to fit. I'll accept this answer. Thanks!